# How does compiler treat datatype?

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-construction, byte

If pointer points to a particular datatype, how does compiler knows (translates) all the properties (size,..., what are the others?) of that specific datatype?

If I have for example:

`char* foo[] = {"abc", "123", "def"};`, then the compiler must make double pointer (pointer to pointer) in order to have this array (of addresses) of arrays (of chars). 
But why is not rather datatype `void*` (as it is addressing -address datatype is void - to string), instead of datatype `char`?

As how i understand it right now - no matter how many address it has to dereference (char**, char***, ...), the datatype declared is for the VALUE finally find. So I understand it as a 'backstop' in the path, by finding the actual value by inspecting the *final value* size. So once the compiler derefence all the references - the path it makes - then it ONLY knows it find the value, because it is one byte long and terminated by null character - as char is (instead of continue dereferencing an address, which is 8 bytes long).

So the question is, how does compiler know a particular datatype. On what property does compiler decide what it is and how long it is. Does it make decision on something else? Or Is my conception correct?

PS: pointer arithmetic is not needed in this example.

Comment: You are making one main essential mistake. You do not think about the pointer arithmetic which can be performed, only about the dereferenced object. Triviality of your example does not help as well. I think you should focus on the language (to better understand pointers, data types and their correlations), not compiler internals at this stage

Comment: I do take arithmetic in account, but in this particular example is not needed.

Comment: 2+2=4 is not good to analyse operators precedence. Same your example. But even there foo++  and (*foo)++ mean something completeley different

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. When you declare something with `char x` or `int x`, the compiler knows the properties and size of `char` or `int` because those are built into the compiler, in its source code. When you declare something with `char *x`, the compiler know it is a pointer, and it knows the properties and size of the pointer because those are built into its source code. And it knows `*x` is a `char` because it knows `x` is a pointer to `char`…

Comment: … Then, when you declare something with `char *x[3]`, the compiler knows `x` is an array of three pointers to `char`. Then it knows `x[1]` is a pointer to `char` and `*x[1]` is a `char`. It knows this because, when it sees `char *x[3]`, it records information about the type of `x` that allows it to track the type through expressions using subscripts and `*` operators.

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Why is this not posted as an answer?  (The first sentence is belied by the rest of the content.  The question is evidently clear enough.)

Comment: @ryyker: The question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*...then the compiler must make double pointer (pointer to pointer)*.

Its not true that the compiler *must* create a char ** in this case.  The compiler will simply treat `char* foo[] = {"abc", "123", "def"};` as an array of 3 pointers, initialized with string literals.

However, it *is* true that if this same variable were to be passed as a function argument, only the addresses of the first element of each array would be passed effectively resulting in your pointer to pointer assertion.  Function prototypes that could pass this variable as an argument include the following:

```
void func2(char *a[]);
void func2(char *a[3]);
void func3(char **a, int order);//includes size information
```

So given `foo` as defined above, calls would be made as follows:

```
func2(foo);
func3(foo, 3);// requires size information
```

Both instances of `foo` will be treated as `char **` when processed by the called function.

*But why is not rather datatype void*...*

In a nutshell, `void *` is a way to allow `type` ambiguity on the programmer side of things. Conversely, when used correctly, there will be no ambiguity at compile time.  (If there is, a good compiler will issue a warning, or error.).

In C the keyword `void` is limited in its use:

- when used as a function return type, it indicates that the function
  does not return a value.
- When it appears in a pointer declaration, it specifies that the
  pointer is universal.
- When used in a function's parameter list, void indicates that the
     function takes no parameters.

The use list does not include creating a non-pointer variable, such as

```
void variable = s;// Illegal, creates a compile-time error.
```

However, `void *` are useful for handling varying data types that might be passed as function parameters. For example, given:

```
typedef union {
    int a;
    char b;
    float c;
    double d;
} TYP; 
TYP typ;

enum {
    INT,
    CHAR,
    FLT,
    DBL
}

void func4(void *a, int type)// void * provides type ambiguity in argument 1 
{                            //i.e. programmer can pass int, char or double
    switch(type) {           
        case 0://int
            typ.a = (int)a;
            break;
        case 1://char
            typ.b = (char)a;
            break;
        case 2://float
            typ.c = *(float *)(a);
            break;
        case 3://double
            typ.d = *(double *)(a);
            break;
    };
}
```

With calling examples:

```
char   c = 'P';
int    d = 1024;
float  e = 14.5;
double f = 0.0000012341;

func4(&c, CHAR);
func4(&d, INT);
func4(&e, FLT);
func4(&f, DBL);
```

Comment: I like this answer, but could you add some a little info about the compiler? especially how it behaves, when it does not know the type (e.g. some unknown structures, or a custom datatype with unknown size (can i say offset?) of bytes.), what are the factors the gcc (my compiler) decides upon to handle it?

Comment: @Herdsman - I am glad this answers some of the questions you ask, but what you are asking in comment is a whole topic onto itself.  However, if you re-read my most recent edit, I do mention the most common compiler reaction to poorly defined or insufficiently defined variables, i.e. that a good compiler will issue a warning or error.  If you would like more detailed information on that topic, post another well written question.

Answer (score 0):

> (as it is addressing -address datatype is void - to string)

`foo` is an array of pointers to chars. (It is not a double pointer)

The elements in `foo` are pointers to chars (written `char*`). That is the type of the elements in the array. The elements in the array are not `void*`, they are `char*`. So the type of the elements in the array is written as `char*`.

`char*` means "pointer to `char`" but `char*` is *also* a perfectly valid data type by itself. It isn't the same as `void*`. You can have pointers to `char*` (written `char**`), arrays of `char*`, and so on.